# Como saber que sitios son mas populares en mi pagina web react

Tags: reactjs, blogger, blog

Estoy haciendo una pagina web tipo blogs y queiro saber cual es el sitio mas popular que hay en mi pagina, para hacer mi pagina web estoy usando react, entonces no se si esto se puede hacer y como hacerlo. Esto para mostrar las entradas mas populares de mi pagina en la pantalla principal